# the key title is showing 3 times on the screen when key link does not exist

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a json with a list of objects with different objects with the keys `title`, `subtitle` or `text`. Sometimes these objects have a key `link` with a link to a website, and sometimes they don't have a link.

This is the list of objects where one object with the key `title` has a additional key `link` with a link to stackoverflow.com.

```
"subscriptions": [
        {
          "type": "title",
          "data": "Subscriptions",
          "link": "stackoverflow.com"

        },
        {
          "type": "subtitle",
          "data": "Active subscriptions"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "data": "These are your active subscriptions"
        }
]
```

I have conditional where i check if object with `title` key exists then show that key. Inside that condition I have a for loop where i iterate through the list of objects and I have conditional where i check if an object has a link then I want to show `Text("has link")` if an object does not have a `link` key then i just want to show  `Text("has no link)` :

```
if (listOfObjects['type'] == "title")

for (var object in listOfObjects)
                        if (object.containsKey("link") == true)
                          
                         Text(
                            "has link",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          )
                        else
                          Text("has no link",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
```

The problem is that I get the text `Text("has no link")` three times in a row like image below:

[image]
Image above is when `link` does exist and it shows the text `has link` but also the three times `has no link`:

So my question is how can i change the condition so i can show the text only one time on the screen if link exists and if it doesn't exist?

**Edit**

Removed unnecessary info

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary operator:

```
object.containsKey("link") == true ? Text("Has link") : null;
```